# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable using max function in for loop

Tags: python

This is part of my code:

```
if click(pt, rec):
            entrytxt = eninput.getText() 
            
            if entrytxt in route: # route dict
                shapeID = route[entrytxt] 
            for i in shapeID:
                coordinates = shape[i] # shape dict
                print(len(coordinates))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ourput for len(coordinates):

180
349
339
184
102
405
185

desired output:
405
```

I'm trying to pick the longest list in length from coordinates,

and use that index to get the longest list from coordinates.

coordinates contains many lists with coordinated values. (not list of lists)

How can I print out 405 only?

Comment: You need to post all of your code so we can see where the error happens. And always post the full error stacktrace.

Comment: You need to inspect what is the type of ```cordinates```

Comment: `len(coordinates)` will give you single integer number. when you pass it to `max()` which expects some iterable, you get this error. We don't know what max you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I solve this?

By not calling `len`? Or by using `len` as as a key function?

You don't really explain what `coordinates` is, or contains. What you wrote certainly doesn't make any sense: `len()` returns a single integer, so this:

```
ourput for print(len(coordinates)):

180
349
339
184
102
405
185
```

can not actually be. Meaning `max(len(coordinates))` can't either when `max` is called with a single parameter, it must be an iterable, which (as the error message tells you) an integer is not.

Comment: In addition - it looks like `coordinates` is a dict/mapping, so probably OP wants to apply len over values in the key function.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print(max(len(coordinates)))` this to `print(max(coordinates))`. As max is expecting a iterable object.